# Datastore backup to bigquery - Duplicate non-list fields are not supported error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I'm creating a bigquery table from a datastore backup file
[image]

For some reason the job fails immediately with error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Found duplicate field 'value_1' in datastore backup schema. Duplicate non-list fields are not supported. (error code: invalid)

I did not find a property "value_1" in any of the datastore entities. Does anybody have an idea of what may cause this error?

Comment: Hi, this is Xiaoxia from Google Cloud Platform Support team, I would like to investigate your issue, but I need some additional information such as project ID.  Can you create a bug in the public issue tracker(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new), and send the link to me? With this I should be able to create a internal case for you and investigate further.

Comment: @XiaoxiaLin https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72075999